# How to lock the S3 bucket policy for some time

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a multithreaded application, hence multiple threads have the capability to create the bucket policy for the same bucket in same time. And all threads use the same IAM user to write the policies. I need to lock the bucket policy for some time so that other threads cannot update the bucket policy. Do we have AWSSDK API for this?

Comment: I think to get better answers, you might want to describe in more detail, what you're trying to accomplish. Almost any solution will come with some tradeoff. For example, while creating the bucket policy, you could create an additional statement that `DENY`s access to `s3:PutBucketPolicy` to all users with a [Date Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Date). This would effectively lock out policy updates for a period of time, but would result in access denials instead.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, is it possible to add new policy in the existing list

Comment: It is very unusual to frequently change a bucket policy. Bucket Policies are usually static. Feel free to edit your question and provide more information about _why_ you need to change the bucket policy and we might be able to offer a better way of achieving your end goal. For example, if you are changing it to add access for users to specific paths, then using a Signed URL _might_ be more appropriate.